# Is it possible to insert values from two different tables which have no relation among them into one table

Tags: sql-server-2008

is it possible to store value into one table (tbl3) from two tables (tbl1) & (tbl2)??,  but (tbl1 & tb2) have no relation among them.
in the picture you could see that Orders table & Product table have no relation. but both the table have Fk with Final table. how to copy data from these two tables into final table? I don't know am I doing right or not.

[image]

Comment: Show us what you tried, and we'll gleefully help!

Comment: insert into Final(Oid,Pid)
select Oid,Pid from Orders,Product

Comment: but it is not giving me the right result.

Comment: If an `Order` involves a `Product`, shouldn't there be another table indicating what products are on the order?  Perhaps an `OrderItems` table?  Or is `Final` meant to be that?

Comment: What is the "right result" that you expect? What would it look like?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, seems what you would like to achieve is `many-to-many` relationship with `Final` being your foreign key table. I also assume it is a cross-join you want to achieve (relating each row in Product with each row of Orders).

```
insert into Final (Oid, Pid)
select p.Pid, o.OId
from (select Pid from Product) p, (select Oid from Orders) o
```